# how do we specify the updation in instead of update triggers

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I am working on triggers and i wonder something now. What happens when we declare an INSTEAD OF UPDATE trigger? How do we pass the parameter of the inserted tuple into the trigger code? Here is the question from the book i study and my answer for that question is below. I am not sure if that is true but at least i need an idea of inserted or updated tuples for triggers when working around with them. Thanks a lot.

Write the following as triggers. In each case, disallow or
undo the modification if it does not satisfy the stated constraint. The database
schema is from the “PC” example of Exercise 2.4.1:
Product(maker, model, type)
PC(model,speed,ram, hd, price)
Laptop(m odel, speed, ram, hd, screen,price)
Printer(model, color, type, price)

! c) When making any modification to the Laptop relation, check that the
average price of laptops for each manufacturer is at least $1500.

My code is ;

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_avg on Laptop
select avg(price) as price, manufacturer from Laptop L
group by(manufacturer)
declare @avg = select price from L
if(@avg<1500)
begin
print 'average price of the manufacturer' + select manufacturer from L where price = @avg +'is less than 1500 update is rejected'
end
```

Comment: One Scenario for using instead of trigger in update is, whenever you update a table column, other columns in the same table or columns from different table needs to be updated

Comment: I know but how do we specifically take the new values i mean how do we pass them as parameters to the new table to be inserted? Is my code correct at that point?

Comment: your code doesn't look like a instead of update trigger code. you didn't specify the table which trigger the triggers operation.

Comment: my mistake sorry i fixed it

Comment: `inserted` and `deleted` are tables so that they can represent the results of set operations. Designing a trigger on the assumption that it  will always process exactly one row is generally a bad plan. If you are absolutely certain there will never be more than one row then _please_ add a check for the number of rows and use `RaIsError` or `Throw` to explicitly inform those who come along later that they have attempted to execute an unacceptable statement. (`if ( select Count(*) from inserted ) > 1 RaIsError( 'FooTable_Insert: No more than one row may be processed.', 25, 42 ) with log`)

Comment: You are probably right about that :) Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't pass parameters to triggers.   Triggers inherently have access to two virtual tables called `inserted` and `deleted`, which contain the rows that were either inserted or deleted by the operation that fired the trigger.

Comment: is deleted for recent updates and inserted for recent insertions? If that is the case what do we use in deletions?

Comment: Oh wait i got it now! So every insertion or deletion could be stored in inserted and deleted tables and we can use them in the triggers accordiong to the needs right?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  There are examples in the MSDN documentation of the CREATE TRIGGER statement.